# Xcode #define variable for all classes?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am using the same source code for different similar apps, the differences are set at runtime using a variable defined using #define by example:

```
// #define Version 1    //  all countries
#define Version 2      // only Austria and Germany

#if Version == 1
    _purchaseController.productID = @"VFULL";
#endif

#if Version == 2
    _purchaseController.productID = @"FULLATDE";
#endif
```

I need this comparison in different classes. Is it possible to define a local variable with #define global for all classes by example in the app delegate?

Comment: Did you try to to define a local variable with #define global for all classes by example in the app delegate?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I created an extra class "`GlobalParameters.h`" and whenever I need the the `Version` variable I `#import "GlobalParameters.h"` to the class. I don't know if it is the best way but it is working as expected.